# Expected value of the number of heads in n tosses, with a twist

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

Suppose we are given a "radioactive" coin. The coin is such that the probability of obtaining a head drops to half its current value each time a head is obtained. If a tail is obtained, the probability remains the same.

Let $P_n(H)$ denote the probability of obtaining a head after $n$ tosses. Also assume that at the beginning of the experiment, $n = 0$ and $P_0(H) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ .

Its clear that

$P_n(H) = \left[\dfrac{P_{n-1}(H)}{2} \times P_{n-1}(H)\right] + \left[P_{n-1}(H) \times (1 - P_{n-1}(H))\right]$

because

$P(H \text{ on nth toss} ) = P(H \text{ on nth toss} |H \text{ on (n-1) th toss} ) P(H \text{ on (n-1) th toss} ) + P(H \text{ on nth toss} |T \text{ on (n-1) th toss} ) P(T \text{ on (n-1) th toss} ) $

This gives us

$P_n(H) = P_{n-1}(H) - \dfrac{(P_{n-1}(H))^2}{2}$

I was wondering how this pans out, is there a closed form solution etc.

Comment: The substitution $P_n(H)=2x_n$ transforms your recurrence equation to the logistic map with parameter $r=1.$ But according to [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html), there are known exact solutions of the logistic map only for $r=-2,$ $r=2$ and $r=4.$

Comment: @ReinhardMeier ahh, I see. Thanks!